# How to populate yii2 checkbox list with drop down in active forum

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have a checkbox list in my yii2 forum.

It is like this.

```
<?php
         $list = ArrayHelper::map(Publisher::find()->all(),'user_id','name');
         echo $form->field($model, 'publisher_name')->widget(Select2::classname(),[
           'data' => $list,
            'options' => [
              'multiple' => true,
              'placeholder' => 'Choose publishers'
            ]
         ]);
        ?>
```

It is taking values from the database. Also, I have used for each to populate the model in the controller. Now I want to populate this checkbox list with the drop downs.

My drop downs are as follows.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'country')->dropDownList(Countries::getCountries(),
                    ['id' => 'country_id', 'prompt' => 'Select  countries'])
                ?>
```

And

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'state')->widget(DepDrop::classname(), [
                        //'data' => Regions::getRegions($model->country),
                        'options' => ['id' => 'region_id', 'prompt' => 'Choose a country first'],
                        'pluginOptions' => [
                            'depends' => ['country_id'],
                            'placeholder' => 'Select a state',
                            'url' => Url::to(['/regions/regions'])
                        ]
                    ]) ?>
```

And

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'city')->widget(DepDrop::classname(), [
                        //'data' => Cities::getCities($model->country),
                        'options' => ['id' => 'city_id', 'prompt' => 'Select a state'],
                        'pluginOptions' => [
                            'depends' => ['country_id','region_id'],
                            'placeholder' => 'Select',
                            'url' => Url::to(['/cities/cities'])
                        ]
                    ]) ?>
```

And there are more drop downs which I will use I want to know what all are the ways I can populate the checkbox list with the array? Are there any ways to do that?

Comment: cant get what you are trying to say

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Simple, there is an array which shows persons in at this way `$list = ArrayHelper::map(Publisher::find()->all(),'user_id','name');` And there are drop downs they are dep drop I just want to populate the above array based on the drop downs.